# How can we implement addition context history for rolling mode?

Tags: node

It looks like with OctezV10 we can now use rolling mode and have it maintain additional contexts in history beyond the default value of 5.  I have a working existing v10.2 rolling node and I have stopped it and issued the command:

```
tezos-node config update --history-mode=rolling:15
```

I see it updated my config.json but when starting the node I get an error that I must use
use an additional config `--force-history-mode-switch`

But when I run the node with that command I get this error:

```
Error:
Failed to get the nth predecessor of BMTrxPyWjYGGbW5HQ9ByhiQfQy4se5gG2T5kAXnxJXt8QjpxTCz. The offset is
invalid: 47386
```

I even tried downloading a new v10.2 import of a rolling snapshot but get same kind of error.  I'm sure there's a way here, but I haven't yet been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This only applies to full mode. and I think the maximum is 7, not 15.